# Attach multiple files (jpeg, m4v, 3gp) to a wordpress post

Tags: php, wordpress

Here is the function that I used to insert attachments to a post.

```
function insert_entries($filename, $parent_post_id){

    $wp_upload_dir = wp_upload_dir();
    $filetype = wp_check_filetype( basename( $filename ), null );

    $attachment = array(
        'guid'           => $wp_upload_dir['url'] . '/' . basename( $filename ), 
        'post_mime_type' => $filetype['type'],
        'post_title'     => preg_replace( '/\.[^.]+$/', '', basename( $filename ) ),
        'post_content'   => '',
        'post_status'    => 'inherit'
            );
    $attach_id = wp_insert_attachment( $attachment, $filename, $parent_post_id );
    $attach_data = wp_generate_attachment_metadata( $attach_id, $filename );
    wp_update_attachment_metadata( $attach_id, $attach_data );
}
```

The issue with this is that, When I am trying to insert any files after inserting a 3gp or m4v file, its not getting inserted. Any insight to solve this is welcome..
Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0):

Atlast got it fixed.
The reason for the issue was when we try to insert any audio or video files the wordpress tries extract its metadata which was causing for a fatal error.

The simple fix for this is to go to includes/image.php and remove all references to wp_read_video_metadata()